# Firebase v3 createUserWithEmailAndPassword .then Promise

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[Firebase v3 Reference Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) indicates that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` returns `firebase.Promise` containing non-null `firebase.User`.

The Firebase v3 [Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) shows the following example

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

My question is, I want to fire a function which adds the user to my `users` node in my Realtime Database.  I want to include the users display name that I collected from the sites registration form.  So, it seems like I want to do a `.then` and if the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method was successful I want to fire a function that writes the new user (with display name) to my Realtime Database `users` node.

How do I modify the example script to a `.then` style?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is the correct use of `then()` and error handling with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    logUser(user); // Optional
}, function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
});

function logUser(user) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
    var obj = {
        "user": user,
        ...
    };
    ref.push(obj); // or however you wish to update the node
}
```

I have another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413111/adding-the-displayname-whilst-using-createuserwithemailandpassword/37414696#37414696).

Comment: What is the benefit of using var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;  versus what comes back in the promise?

Comment: There is none. It is equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Check this, you need to read payload or snapshot(firebase term)

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
                .then((authData) => {
                    console.log("User created successfully with payload-", authData);
                    //Write code to use authData to add to Users
                }).catch((_error) => {
                    console.log("Login Failed!", _error);
                })
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did and it worked.

```
        function registerUsername(email,password,displayName){
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
```

Comment: @MithunPattankar I voted your answer up but accepted the other one just bcs it was easier for me to read.  The ES6 you used is sharp but not as simple to me.  Thank you very much for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future stumbles upon it, an await-async example:

```
export const doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = async (pEmail, pPassword) => {
    try {
        const authResult = await app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(pEmail, pPassword);
         usersRef.doc(authResult.user.uid)
            .set({
                email: pEmail,
                created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              });
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```