# There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

```
export const createEmployee = ({ email, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) =>{`
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword ( email,password )
    .then(
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email,password )
      .then(Actions.profile())
    )
  };
};
```

Comment: Catch to see if you had an error. `.catch(function(error) ...`

Comment: no errors but thanks though helped me to dig deeper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth), after the success of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` the user is ***automatically signed-in***.

> Create a new account by passing the new user's email address and
>   password to createUserWithEmailAndPassword:
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
>   // Handle Errors here.
>   var errorCode = error.code;
>   var errorMessage = error.message;
>   // ...
> });
> ```
>
> If the new account was created, **the user is signed in automatically**.
>   Have a look at the Next steps section below to get the signed in user
>   details.
>   [...]

Look also at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511285/firebase-v3-createuserwithemailandpassword-then-promise).

So in your promise you can just get you already authenticated user like that:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

No need to make `signInWithEmailAndPassword` call.